# Laravel API Angular 5 app en servidor compartido

Tags: angular, apache

Tengo una app de angular 5 y una api en laravel desplegadas en la carpeta pública de un servidor compartido. La aplicación angular está en la carpeta public_html y el api en una carpeta llamada api dentro de public_html.

Mintras usaba hashlocationstrategy, es decir, las rutas de angular se generaban así www.tnoradio.com/#login, todo funcionaba perfecto, pero al realizar el cambio para pathlocationstrategy de manera que mis rutas aparezcan así www.tnoradio.com/login, recibo error 500 del api, no funciona ni siquiera el home.

Este es el archivo .httaccess que agregué en el root (public_html) para que funcione el pathlocationstrategy de angular.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Estas utilizando un servidor linux?

Comment: quiero pensar que tu api esta en un subdominio de tu servidor compartido o estan en el mismo dominio ? como invocas los servicios de tu api en el angular ?